# Does javascript have something like python `__slots__`

Tags: javascript, python, memory

Python `__slots__` allows a more compact representation for instances.

Does javascript provide something similar? Use `ArrayBuffer` as a custom allocator? Any examples?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Care to elaborate? (no luck with a search)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: The first result before or after “did you mean flyweight”, both unrelated to what `__slots__` does?

Comment: @zjk: JavaScript objects with consistent shapes are already pretty compact in that way on the usual engines, but yes, you could probably use `ArrayBuffer` if you needed the smallest possible representation for a collection of some type.

Comment: @Ry- Are there any libraries use the buffer as mem alloc?